# TextBox DataBind()

Tags: c#, data-binding, web-applications, textbox

I'm new to .NET and C#. I'm been playing around with Web Applications in .NET and I'm confused on how to bind data to a simple text box. Sure I can make a make a data set and then say 
`textBox1.Text = myDataSet.WhateverTheFunctionIsToGetATableName()` 
but that's not really binding the data. I've found the method DataBind() but it has no parameters and I can't find another method to go with it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does your markup look like? Any [data-binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)? Why do you think that the text property of a `TextBox` is the right way to bind?

Comment: no. all i did was drag and drop a text box on the screen and then wanted to learn how to bind data to it.

Comment: What tutorials did you follow?

Comment: i haven't followed any tutorial per say. I just usually google things that i'd like to be able to do and i cant seem find anything on this. i see things for web forms but not web applications and their methods are different

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching databindings instead of databind? Those two are different.